# Golang Protoc Message Variable Interface Type

Tags: go, microservices, protocol-buffers, grpc, proto

My service endpoint has this reponse:

```
type Response struct {
    Value     interface{}
    ValueType string

}
```

I try to write a protoc file. What should I write instead of Value has interface type in Message:

```
message ValueGetResponse {
    string Value = 1;
    string ValueType = 2;
}
```

Comment: usually you model your service responses *after* the proto schema, and not the other way around

Answer (score 4):

You can have a look at `google.protobuf.Any` (https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#any)

```proto
import "google/protobuf/any.proto";

message ValueGetResponse {
    google.protobuf.Any Value = 1;
    string ValueType = 2;
}
```

It's not an `interface{}`, but also allow to have more flexibility.

And pay attention to the comment from @blackgreen under your question.